# how can i assign values to my c program with php

Tags: php, html, c, cmd

I'm trying to run a C program of adding two numbers with PHP in a web browser. But when I run the command 
exec"gcc name.c -o a & a" it
returns some garbage result like sum is : 8000542.00. It doesn't ask for any input.
I want to give inputs to scanf from the browser. Please suggest to me how can I resolve my problem.
I have tried this but couldn't handle it successfully.

```
$desc = array(0=> array ('pipe','w'), 1=> array ('pipe','r'));
$cmd = "C:\xampp\htdocs\add.exe";
$pipes=array();
$p = proc_open($cmd,$desc,$pipes);

if(is_resource($p))
{

 echo stream_get_contents($pipes[0]);
 fclose($pipes[0]);

 $return_value=proc_close($p);
 echo $return_value;
```

Comment: Are you trying to compile the C code just before launching it?

Comment: yeah i am trying to compile C code before lauching it  @AntonH